# Python/Pandas: Optimize Speed of unstack('var').fillna(0).stack('var')

Tags: python, pandas

I have data containing information on **product id** as `i`, **time of offer** as `t`, **merchant id** as `m` and price. For each product `i`, there is a list of times `t` at which I have prices for all merchants `m`.

When a particular merchant `m` does not have any offers for `i` at `t`, the entry for `(i,t,m)` is simply missing.

I would like an entry with a price of zero to signal that there is no offer by this merchant at this time.

**Note** that the merchants for each product are separate: I want to add entries for merchants which appeared on *this* product at some point, not for all merchants that appeared on any product at some point.

The following code achieves my desired result:

```
def addMissingMerchants(pDF):
    return pDF.set_index(['i','t','m']).unstack('m').fillna(0).stack('m').reset_index();

df = df.groupby('i').progress_apply(addMissingMerchants).drop('i',axis=1).reset_index().drop('level_1',axis=1);
```

However, this code is quite slow: it processes about 15 products per second on my system.

**Is there any way to achieve the same result faster?**

Minimal working example:

```
          i                   t        m              p
40181    3996 2018-08-26 02:33:45      162082         67.90
40182    3996 2018-08-26 03:14:10      162082         67.90
40194    3996 2018-08-26 02:33:45      193879         58.00
40195    3996 2018-08-26 03:14:10      193879         58.00
40210    3996 2018-08-26 03:14:10      256684         57.98
40226    3996 2018-08-26 02:33:45      373084         58.00
40227    3996 2018-08-26 03:14:10      373084         58.00
40247    3996 2018-08-26 02:33:45     1238707         53.98
40248    3996 2018-08-26 03:14:10     1238707         53.98
```

Desired Output:

```
     i                      t      m              p
0    3996 2018-08-26 02:33:45      162082         67.90
1    3996 2018-08-26 02:33:45      193879         58.00
2    3996 2018-08-26 02:33:45      256684          0.00
3    3996 2018-08-26 02:33:45      373084         58.00
4    3996 2018-08-26 02:33:45     1238707         53.98
5    3996 2018-08-26 03:14:10      162082         67.90
6    3996 2018-08-26 03:14:10      193879         58.00
7    3996 2018-08-26 03:14:10      256684         57.98
8    3996 2018-08-26 03:14:10      373084         58.00
9    3996 2018-08-26 03:14:10     1238707         53.98
```

(Note the new line starting with 2)

Current time cost:

```
%%timeit
addMissingMerchants(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.59 ms per loop
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Added the minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

Instead of un- and restacking, reindex the whole dataframe. First build a list of tuples:

```
tuples = [];
for i, productData in df.groupby('i'):
    tList = productData.t.unique();
    for m in productData.m.unique():
        tuples.extend([(i,m,t) for t in tList]);
```

Then use the tuples to reindex the dataframe:

```
df = df.set_index(['i','m','t']) 
df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')] 
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples,names=['i','m','t'])
df = df.reindex(idx,fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

This takes a couple of minutes to execute for the whole dataframe, much better than the groupby-unstack-restack solution (which took around 1.5h).